# Rewriting Join SQL query into a Subquery

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am having trouble changing the join sql statement below into subqueries. Kindly assist. Thanks

```
1.SELECT airports.NAME 
  FROM airports inner join 
       cities on cities.iata_code= airports.cty_iata_code INNER JOIN 
       FLIGHT_PROFILES ON AIRPORTS.IATA_CODE = FLIGHT_PROFILES.FROM 
  GROUP BY FLIGHT_PROFILES.FROM 
  ORDER BY COUNT(FLIGHT_PROFILES.FROM) DESC 
  LIMIT 1;

2.select c.Name, c.cou_iata_code as Country_Code 
  from cities c inner join 
       flight_profiles f on c.iata_code <> f.to 
  group by c.cou_iata_code 
  ORDER BY C.NAME asc;

3.select f.flt_numb as FLIGHT_NUMBER, a.name as DESTINATION_AP, a2.name as ALTERNATIVE_AP 
  from flight_profiles f inner join 
       airports a on f.to = a.iata_code inner join 
       airports a2 on a.cty_iata_code = a2.cty_iata_code 
  where a.iata_code != a2.iata_code;
```

Comment: I can't see how you want to use sub queries for those (and generally sub queries are not that efficient in MySQL). But your first query appears to be very strange, having the column flight_profiles.from as by the GROUP BY field and also the field acted on by the COUNT aggregate function.

Comment: that first query is meant to return the name of the airport with the most flights departing from it. Only return one row and one column of data. For sake of knowledge on how to use sub queries is why i want to use sub queries for this. Using sub queries is giving me trouble and i need help

Comment: For the first query I think you need to GROUP BY airports.name to get the result you want. It would be possible to rewrite this as a sub query (I will try an answer in a moment), but the 2nd and third queries do not really suit the use of sub queries.

Answer (score 0):

Initial fix for your original first query.

```
SELECT airports.NAME 
FROM airports 
INNER JOIN cities ON cities.iata_code = airports.cty_iata_code 
INNER JOIN FLIGHT_PROFILES ON AIRPORTS.IATA_CODE = FLIGHT_PROFILES.FROM 
GROUP BY airports.NAME 
ORDER BY COUNT(FLIGHT_PROFILES.`FROM`) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Using a couple of sub queries. This gets the counts of flights for each 'FROM' field, and then gets the max of the counts. This is joined against another sub query to get all the counts for each FROM, joining where the count matches the max count. This avoids using a LIMIT on the query (although it will bring back 2 cities if both have the same high number of flights).

```
SELECT airports.NAME 
FROM airports 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT `FROM`, COUNT(*) AS flights_from_count
    FROM FLIGHT_PROFILES
    GROUP BY `FROM`
) sub2 ON airports.IATA_CODE = sub2.`FROM` 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(flights_from_count) AS max_flights_from_count
    FROM
    (
        SELECT `FROM`, COUNT(*) AS flights_from_count
        FROM FLIGHT_PROFILES
        GROUP BY `FROM`
    ) sub1
) sub3
ON sub2.flights_from_count = sub3.max_flights_from_count
```

In this case I would suggest that avoiding using sub queries would be the most efficient and easily readable solution.

Small note. You appear to have a field called FROM. I would suggest that in general you avoid ever having any column names that are SQL key words